# How to search records between two coordinates using solr spatial search

Tags: solr

I have a start lat long and an ending lat long and I have to search other records between these points using solr spatialSearch. Thanks in advance if anyone can help me.

Best Records...

Aisha Zafar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Solr's Bounding-box](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#bbox_-_Bounding-box_filter) filter to find the records between the box but it works with single point (lat,lon) and a distance.

If you have two points then you can find the record between this box by using range query. Query could be something like :

> ..&fq=latField:[lat1 TO lat2] AND lonField:[lon1 TO lon2]

Comment: Thank you so much. Thats a good solution but I have latlng in single field separated with comma.

Comment: @aishazafar Then you can do fieldName:[lat1,long TO lat2,lng2]
Just make sure that lat1<=lat2 and lon1<=lon2

Answer (score 0):

This is the solr query:
just change the pt as a search coordinate and the distance d as a radius of a circle.
fq={!geofilt sfield=coordinates}&pt=10.737845823323038,106.65631819042972&d=2.8'

each document which is indexed from solr with this schema.xml config:

<
field name="coordinates" type="geohash" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

and document object should contain a field like this:
    $fields['coordinates'] = implode(',', $post->getCoordinates()->getLatLng());