# Solr Spatial search two coordinates

Tags: solr

I'm trying to query with the lat/long bounds but am having troubles.

fq=geo-coordinates:"[(40.87967,-74.0183) TO (40.7,-73.9072)]" does not work, I have also tried

fq=geo-coordinates:"[(40.87967 TO 40.7,-74.0183 TO -73.9072)]"

I am aware there is a coordinate plus a radius query but I need this query to be strictly between two coordinates.

This question is similar: [How to search records between two coordinates using solr spatial search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051048/how-to-search-records-between-two-coordinates-using-solr-spatial-search)

But the answer does not take into consideration a single location_rpt schema field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first try was *almost* right. Those parenthesis shouldn't have been there, nor the double-quotes:

```
fq=geo-coordinates:[40.87967,-74.0183 TO 40.7,-73.9072]
```

The quotes you had made the query look like a field/term query, which this isn't -- it's a range query.